# Broadcasting issues in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, array-broadcasting

I am trying to fit PCA on the train and test data.

```
X_train.shape

(2735, 219)
```

PCA:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=30)
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Test data:

```
test_values.shape
(395, 219)
```

Transformation:

```
test_values = pca.transform(test_values)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (395,219) (30,)
```

I am not sure on why there is a broadcast error, both the numpy arrays have the same columns 219.
Any suggestions please

Comment: Are you using ipython, jupyter notebook or something that preserves variable state?

Comment: You overwrite your original training data with some transformed values. That's far from good practice. Istead do something like `X_trans = pca.fit_transfor(X_train)`.

Comment: This way you'll circumvent the problem you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that it is a preserved variable issue if you are using ipython, notebook or something like that. If that is not the case, you may ignore this answer.

Consider the following cells.

[image]

When I run these cells, everything is fine. However, if I try to run second cell again I got this error:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (395,219) (30,)`

It is because X_train is now a `2735, 30` matrix and pca is fitted on this matrix so it expects `n, 30` matrix.

If you clear your variables or reorganize your code such that it does not fit on already transformed data, the problem can be solved.

Comment: Thats exactly what was happening!

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer. But to help you to understand the scenario, I am posting this!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.random.randn(2735, 219)
pca = PCA(n_components=30)
pca.fit(X)

test_values = np.random.randn(395 , 219)

pca.transform(test_values)
```

The above codes works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your example, and everything works fine:

```
x_train = np.random.randint(10, size=50).reshape(10, 5)
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
print(x_train.shape)
x_train = pca.fit_transform(x_train)
test_values = np.random.randint(10, size=100).reshape(20, 5)
print(test_values.shape)
test_values = pca.transform(test_values)
print(test_values.shape)
```

The code outputs:

```
(10, 5)
(20, 5)
(20, 3)
```

Check that the error appears on the line with PCA. Looks like you are doing some operation with the arrays of wrong shape.

Comment: It's because the line X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train). He overwrote his original training data with the transformend values and retrained the PCA.